# Can readlink return 0 with non-zero bufsize?

Tags: c

I'm trying to analyse some code (not written by myself) which calls `readlink` with a positive `bufsize`, and then tests if the result is zero. I can't see how the result can be zero, with everything I've tried it is either -1, size of the real link or size of the soft link.

Can the result be zero, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX description of [`readlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlink.html) says:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>     Upon successful completion, readlink() shall return the count of bytes placed in the buffer. Otherwise, it shall return a value of -1, leave the buffer unchanged, and set errno to indicate the error.

Since the empty string is not a valid file name, I can see no way that the return value will be zero if the `bufsize` is bigger than 0.

Comment: That's as I thought, thank you. Just wanted to check if there was something peculiar or implementation defined not mentioned in the man pages. I'll accept the answer if no-one else answers different soon.

Answer (score 2):

According to [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/readlink.html)

> Upon successful completion, readlink() shall return the count of bytes placed in the buffer. Otherwise, it shall return a value of -1, leave the buffer unchanged, and set errno to indicate the error

Here two possible answers

1. it is highly possible that you've found the bug in implementation (author was not aware of spec)
2. author of code discovered on practice, that platform not conforming to spec and return 0 instead of -1 and wrote this non-portable piece of code